# How to dynamically generate page x of y using javascript?

Tags: itext

I have a few types of PDF report. Every report has its own header and footer with different content and format. All of them should have "page X of Y" field. All those reports are merged into one PDF file.

How can I implement the X of Y problem? I thought it should be very easy task using some simple javascript. But unfortunately it is not :(

How can I achieve this? I just need insert a text to every single page (probably using PDFStamper) and run a javascript to generate appropriate X of Y when the merged document is opened.

Comment: Why you need javascript here??You're talking about page number problem with itext..right??

Comment: Yes. I need to dynamically generate page numbers in the document. Because every page could have different position, font, color of the page number (the document is composed of several different PDF files).

Comment: The question needs clarification: JavaScript or Java? (If JavaScript, the question is absurd.) Also: the OP says the examples on itextpdf.com all add page numbers using the same style. That's a lame excuse: these are just examples, you can change the examples using whatever style you need, even using different styles for different pages. It's not clear however where the styles are stored. If in existing AcroForm fields, it's not clear if the document needs to be flattened (if not: this can lead to a number of problems). In short: the question reveals a lack of understanding of PDF.

Comment: Why is javascript absurd? I just need to implement something like this: hey page, here is a text field with a page number, update it to appropriate state depending on what is your true position in the document and use the format it has right now. This page can be then merged with as many PDF as you wish and it will have always correct page number.

Answer (score 2):

If by javascript you mean Java, here are a couple of [examples](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=223). Since you are not creating the PDF file from scratch, you'll be better off with the second example.

If you really mean javascript, then iText is definitely **not** the tool you want to use.

Comment: I know those examples. They are all about inserting the page numbers with same style to same position in all pages. But I need to change (or fill in) existing text fields with predefined styles and position.

Comment: Do you mean the different files you are merging already have the "Page X of Y" present, and you need to modify the values? If not, what prevents you from adapting the examples I gave (specially the second one) and set the style and position at your will?

Comment: Every page in a PDF I generate has a text PdfFormField with defined position and style. But it doesn't have set any text. The document itself contains a javascript which is evaluated when the document is open and it loops all those page fields and set its text to appropriate page number. But I don't know if there is a better solution.

Comment: Ok, your question starts to make more sense. Please edit your question by adding to it the different comments you made, and make clear you want to use *Acrobat JavaScript*, that you have form fields already in you document, etc...